# Call overloaded method using template

Tags: java, templates, overloading

There are three classes, `ChildChild`, `Child` and `Parent` one extending another. I call method using template for most outer class and I would like to get method `doSomething` called to print "CHILD". Instead of that previous method gets called.

```
class Test {
    public <T extends Parent> void doSomething(T input) {
        System.out.println("PARENT");
    }
    public <T extends Child> void doSomething(T input) {
        System.out.println("CHILD");
    }

    public <T extends Parent> void run(T input) { doSomething(input); }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.run(new ChildChild());
    }
}
```

Is that because of method run defining template only for Parent class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when the compiler erases the generic type parameters, they are replaced by their type bounds, so your `run` method becomes :

```
public void run(Parent input) { doSomething(input); }
```

and the overloaded methods become :

```
public void doSomething(Parent input) {
    System.out.println("PARENT");
}
public void doSomething(Child input) {
    System.out.println("CHILD");
}
```

Therefore `doSomething(Parent input)` is called (remember that method overloading resolution is determined at compile time, using the compile-time types), regardless of the runtime type of the instance you are passing to the `run` method.